# Pine Script-Problems with the policy tester

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

Why can't the policy tester trade at the specified price that day?Can you only do the day's trading at the closing price?

How should I operate to meet the requirements in my question?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to enter a trade at a specific price, you need to place a limit order by using the `strategy.entry()` function. By default it will enter with a market order.

> strategy.entry(id, direction, qty, limit, stop, oca_name, oca_type,
> comment, alert_message) → void
>
> ***limit (series int/float)*** An optional parameter. Limit price of the order. If it is specified, the order type is either 'limit', or
> 'stop-limit'. 'NaN' should be specified for any other order type.
>
> ***stop (series int/float)*** An optional parameter. Stop price of the order. If it is specified, the order type is either 'stop', or
> 'stop-limit'. 'NaN' should be specified for any other order type.

Comment: If I use limit, then I won't be able to trade on the same day. Is that all it has to be?

Comment: You can use a smaller timeframe as your entry and get data from higher timeframes to confirm your signal.